# How to differentiate between client types in rest method?

Tags: html, xml, rest, client

I have a jax-rs rest service for which I've written an Android client.

The rest service exposes methods to CRUD reports. A http get request returns a list of reports in an xml structure.

Now, if I access the service from a browser, I want the http get request to return html instead of xml.

Can I overload the method to return different results for different clients or do I have to implement a separate rest method for browser clients?

I also considered using the same xml structure for both and including an xml stylesheet for the browser, but I can't figure out how to put the xslt link in the autogenerated xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Quentin's answer is a good pointer in the right direction, it is not jax-rs specific.

The [jax-rs specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf) defines the annotation @Produces in section 3.5

> Application classes can declare the supported request and response
>   media types using the @Consumes and 23 @Produces annotations
>   respectively. These annotations MAY be applied to a resource method, a
>   resource 24 class, or to an entity provider (see section 4.2.3). Use
>   of these annotations on a resource method overrides 25 any on the
>   resource class or on an entity provider for a method argument or
>   return type. In the absence of 26 either of these annotations, support
>   for any media type (“*/*”) is assumed.

The mime type declared with @Produces is automatically matched with the [HTTP Accept Request Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) of the request. That means that to differentiate between client requests, you can define resource methods with different @Produces declarations.

In my case I needed a method that returned xml and a method that returned html, so I declared two methods in the resource /reports:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String getReportsAsHtml(){...}
```

And

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public List<Report> getReportsAsXml() {...}
```

Please refer to Quentin's comment about Accept Header preferences for the final part of the puzzle

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTTP Accept Request Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1)

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, but could you clarify for me? If the request comes from the browser, is the preferred accept mime type normally html?

Comment: The accept header your Android client sends should indicate a strong preference for `application/xml`. Browsers will indicate either a preference for `text/html` or give that and XML equal weight with `*/*`. If the service has a weak preference for HTML it will deliver HTML to browsers and XML to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Just send it as XML all the time and use a stylesheet.  In this case it sounds like the stylesheet can be pretty primitive, so just use CSS.  Here is an example of an XML document that uses a CSS stylesheet and where that stylesheet is backwards compatible to older versions of IE.

http://mailmarkup.org/hcl/hcl1_0-documentation.xsd

Notice in the stylesheet the duplication to counter the unnecessary mention of namespace declarations.  That is how I was able to achieve compatibility with IE.